# VECM - Impulse reponse function - statsmodels - AttributeError: 'lr_effects'

Tags: statsmodels, vector-error-correction-model, impulse-response

I am using statsmodels version '0.11.1'. I am trying to sum cumulative effects of using the impulse response function derived of a VECM, but I am getting an AttributeError regarding 'lr_effects'. As far as I am aware you should be able to retrieve the cumulative effects from an impulse response function derived from a VECM also right? Or am I missing something? My code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import VECM

mod = VECM(endog=model_merged.rename(columns=rename_dict)[for_model],
           k_ar_diff=3,
           coint_rank=1,
           deterministic='cili'
          ).fit()
mod.summary()`

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20, 40)
num_periods = 10
ir = mod.irf(periods=num_periods)
ir.plot_cum_effects()
```

The error I receive is: AttributeError: 'IRAnalysis' object has no attribute 'lr_effects'

Plotting the regular impulse reponse function using ir.plot() does work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From a quick look, the function `BaseIRAnalysis.plot_cum_effects` reads the property `lr_effects`, but it is not set at all in the constructor of `BaseIRAnalysis` when the parameter `vecm` is `True`. A comment implies that this is because "long-run effects may be infinite for VECMs". This is a bug, it should at least give a useful error, or since (from what I can tell) `lr_effects` is only used for plotting, it should just not be included in the plot in that case.